# Laravel: Authenticate User From Another Web Application

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

Here is the thing. I already have custom web application with my own auth service. I already have table of users and it's works for a long time as well.
Currently, I want to add a laravel app into my custom project. I just placed the laravel folder into the root directory of my application (now I can get access into the laravel app by this query mysite.com/laravel/public).

So, I want to get authenticated in the Laravel application when login into the main application. What can I do?

Currently, I want to authenticate user inside my old project and then just "told" laravel that everything ok and those user authenticated.

I'm using Laravel 5.1

Comment: You would need to somehow share the session data or do some other token based authentication.

Comment: Obviously... That is exactly what I need, but can't get how to do it.